# IE10 d3.v3.js error: Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference

Tags: d3.js, internet-explorer-10

My page is loading perfectly in IE9, Safari, Chrome & Firefox.

But when it coems to IE10 , it throws error :
*Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference* 
in [d3.v3.js](http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js)
at line : d3_window.CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.

```
 try {
    d3_document.createElement("div").style.setProperty("opacity", 0, "");
  } catch (error) {
    var d3_style_prototype = d3_window.CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype, d3_style_setProperty = d3_style_prototype.setProperty;
    d3_style_prototype.setProperty = function(name, value, priority) {
      d3_style_setProperty.call(this, name, value + "", priority);
    };
  }
```

I am not getting what exactly is being done here.

In try block even though setProperty method we can see in debugger on `d3_document.createElement("div").style`
it is throwing *error* as :
*Object doesn't support property or method 'setProperty'*

In catch block it tries to access prototype of window's `CSSStyleDeclaration` , but that is undefined.

Anybody occured with same problem while using [d3.v3.js](http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js)

Comment: Yes I have the same problem but I haven't found the solution yet. Might have something to do with IEs lack of ECMA 5. I had an issue with Array.map https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I have the same error, same line using IE 9.  Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This can be fixed with a `DOCTYPE`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And a `meta` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Without those, IE will go into quirks mode and not understand what `CSSStyleDeclaration` is.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem which used to happen randomly, after some research i concluded that it's setting invalid css properties ( from IE point of view ) that caused it, in my case:
     `someSvg.append('svg:text')
            .text(function (d) { return d.label; })
            .attr('text-anchor', 'left')`

Where it should have been

```
.attr('text-anchor', 'start')
```

So my advice would be to review all from-scritpt-stylings, or even better - move them to css completely. After such fix it should work like charm in IE9+

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this is a known issue and unlikely to get fixed.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/8lQ2BCR45BM

The work-around is to load d3 selectively - this works for me -

```
// load d3.js selectively
try { 
            // if this doesnt throw an error then we can load d3.js 
            // this is known to fail in IE < 8
            document.createElement("div").style.setProperty("opacity", 0, "")

            var d3Script = document.createElement( "script" )

            d3Script.src = "@Href("~/JavaScript/d3.js")"

            d3Script.onload = function (){
                // do stuff
            }

            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( d3Script )
} catch( error ) {
            // upgrade your browser
}
```