# d3 is undefined error

Tags: d3.js, runtime-error

This is really driving me crazy.
  http://www.myethiopia.org/QuickLinks/Stuff/Data/amtigray.html
   this works in firefox and chrome. I am getting the following errors in IE9.
1. HTML1204: myethiopia.org is running in Compatibility View because 'Display all websites in Compatibility View' is checked. 
2. SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'prototype': object is null or undefined 
3. SCRIPT5009: 'd3' is undefined

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  There's [a similar question on StackOverflow over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196622/ie10-d3-v3-js-error-unable-to-get-property-prototype-of-undefined-or-null-ref) that had the answer for me.

Long story, short, be sure to include these two lines at the top of your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

That fixed it for me.  There are other suggestions at that link that might work for you, too.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in d3.v3.js well according to IE it is . The offending line appears to be:

```
 d3_document.createElement("div").style.setProperty("opacity", 0, "");
```

You'll likely need to modify the d3 library in order to resolve this. There are some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196622/ie10-d3-v3-js-error-unable-to-get-property-prototype-of-undefined-or-null-ref) that you should review.

I appreciate this is not a complete answer however this is the reason for the error and hopefully will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I found the real reason this is happening. It is due to IE's compatiblilty view setting. Make sure it is **off** per Mike bostock.   and please stop using IE.   Microsoft goes out of its way to make their browser difficult to use.